# Making a Bash script that can open multiple terminals and run wget in each

Tags: bash, terminal, wget

I have to download bulks of over 100,000 docs from a databank using this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
IFS=$'\n'       
set -f          
for line in $(cat < "$1")
do
  wget https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/${line}.txt
done
```

The first time it took over a week to download all the files (all under 8Kb) so I tried opening multiple terminals and running a split of the total.txt (10 equal splits of 10000 files in 10 terminals) and in just 14 hours I had all the documents downloaded, is there a way to make a script do that for me?

this is a sample of what the list looks like:

```
D7E6X7
A0A1L9C3F2
A3K3R8
W0K0I7
```

Answer (score 1):

gnome-terminal -e command
or
xterm -e command
or
konsole -e command
Or
terminal -e command

Answer (score 0):

There is an another alternative to make it fast.

Right now your downloads are synchronized i.e next download process is not started until current one is finished.

Search for how to make command asynchronous/run in background on unix.

Answer (score 0):

When you were doing this by hand, opening multiple terminals made sense. If you want to script this, you can run multiple *processes* from one terminal/script. You could use [xargs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) to start multiple processes simultaneously:

```
xargs -a list.txt -n 1 -P 8 -I @ bash -c "wget https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/@.txt"
```

Where:

- `-a list.txt` tells xargs to use the list.txt file as input.
- `-n 1` tells xargs to use a maximum of one argument (from the input) for each command it runs.
- `-P 8` tells xargs to run 8 commands at a time, you can change this to suit your system/requirements.
- `-I @` tells xargs to use "@" to represent the input (i.e. the line from your file).